# Is there a file url shortcut for my app's home directory?

Tags: android

You can references asset files with a file url by using "android_asset", as in `file:///android_asset/whatever`.  Is there something equivalent for the app's home directory?  I'll be using the references in a static html file, so I don't want to call `getFilesDir()`.  I'm pretty sure the directory will always be `/data/data/[package]/files`, but in case that is different on a weird device, I'm wondering if there's a file url shortcut.

Comment: i think you are asking something like this? `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    +"/Android/data/[package]/files/"`

for internl storage that is private to the app is always `/data/data/[package]/files` and for diabase it is `/data/data/[package]/databases/`

Comment: I don't think it gonna be change in near future. It is fine to use same /data/data.....

Comment: We're going to move forward with just doing file:///data/data/[package]/files/[filename].  I'm a little concerned that we'll find a strange device that puts its files in a different directory, but that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: I understood. You shouldn't worry so much. Android [recommends](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) doing that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your file into `res/raw` folder. For example your file is `page1.html`, to use it in your activity:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.page1);
```

More references: [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: File is created dynamically, referenced from a static HTML file.  Since the HTML file is static, the file reference can't be dynamically changed.

Comment: Looking at your comment above (not the answer, but I'll give it to you ;), the answer is (basically) no, no special reference for that folder.  It seems like everything is OK anyway.  No problems so far.